# Change the Windows file permission using Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

Is there any way to change the file permission using Gradle. When I download the code from source control all the files are in read-only mode. But I want to update project config files version according to Gradle script property value.

I have used ant.propertyfile task to update the conf.properties file abc key.

```
ant.propertyfile(

   file: "/conf/conf.properties") {
   entry( key: "abc", value: "value1")
}
```

when I try to build the project I am getting access denied error message. Please can some one help me to sole this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build an `Exec` task to change the permissions on the file.

```
task makeReadWrite(type:Exec) {
    workingDir '../source/path'

    //on windows:
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'attrib -r file.txt'
}
```

I haven't tested this but it should get you in the ballpark.

As an alternative, have you considered putting the version information in the `MANIFEST.MF` file? Gradle includes utilities to generate a useful manifest. Then you just have to read the manifest in your code which is pretty easy.

The side benefit here is that you never have to worry about editing source controlled files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me in Windows, the `Exec` task within a `gradle.kts` file would look thus:

```
tasks {
    register<Exec>("makeFileExecutable") {
        workingDir(rootDir)
        commandLine("cmd", "755", "path/to/folderorfile")
    }
}
```